# JavaScript parentNode skipping container div

Tags: javascript, html

I have some simple HTML and want a div to take on a property of its container div once the page has been loaded. Here is an example of the HTML:

```
<div id=menuBar>
  <div id=menuButton>
    <div id=menuButtonSub>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I run this JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("menuButtonSub").parentNode.id
```

It returns "menuBar" rather than "menuButton". Any clues as to why? Still learning, but most things have been smooth up until now.

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
#menuBar {
    width:100%;
    min-height:50px;
    background-color:#808080;
}
.menuButton {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:20px;
    min-height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:50px;
    float:left;
}
.menuButton:hover {
    color: #1a448f;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.menuButtonSub {
    background-color:red;
    color:#ffffff;
    min-height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Can't repro: http://jsfiddle.net/g75wu6vv/ . Maybe your HTML/DOM isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/rc6de6ye/

Comment: and for me I know I kind of late, but this is the first time I created a js-fiddle of my own so I post it anyway :) http://jsfiddle.net/8nfhderx/

Comment: Odd. It certainly does work on js-fiddle, but it is still returning menuBar in Visual Studio. Must be something somewhere I am not seeing. Thanks for validating the code, anyway!

Comment: Looks like you just confused selectors, providing that in HTML you have ids and in CSS classes. So there is probably just some confusion not reflected in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this with the following code.  You most likely have an error/typo in your HTML (I'm missing a tag end character on the menuBar div).  Try running it through a validator.

```js
document.body.innerHTML += document.getElementById("menuButtonSub").parentNode.id;
```

```html
<div id='menuBar'
  <div id='menuButton'>
    <div id='menuButtonSub'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```